# CGridView Pagination not working. Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, pagination

I have a form in my view which selects columns from a dropdown list. The SqlDataProvider is used to get the data from the generated Query

I have been trying to use CGridView with SQLDataProvider, its working a bit fine, but still having some issues with pagination. I don't have any keyField so I give it my first column, and without keyField it doesn't work.

Here is my action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $tables = Yii::app()->db->schema->getTables();

    if(isset($_POST['yt0'])){ //if from submitted

        $query = $this->generateQuery();

        $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( ' . $query . ' ) as count')->queryScalar();

        $dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
            'keyField' => $firstColumn,
            'totalItemCount'=> $count,
            'pagination'=> array(
                'pageSize'=>20,
            ),
        ));

        $columns = $this->getColumnNamesWithoutTable();

        $this->render('index',
            array(  'tables' => $tables,
                    'query' => $query,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'columns' => $columns
            )
        );

    }else{

        $this->render('index', array('tables' => $tables));
    }
}
```

Here is widget code in the view, according to what I have read, pagination should work automatically, is it because I am using a custom query rather than Yii Models ?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'enablePagination'=> true,
));
```

It shows the data first time, but next button doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I just added totalitemcount in the sqldataprovider and it worked for me, if anyone is still wondering,

```
 $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
                'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>10,
                ),
                'totalItemCount'=>'100000'
 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

'keyField' => $firstColumn

What is the $firstColumn value.

Keyfield must be index of array retiring by the CSqlDataProvider